# Jquery Function not working

Tags: jquery, html

The function like that work fine

```
$(function() {
    $('#square').udraggable({
    containment: [ 0, 0, 8000, 8000],
    grid:        [ 30, 30 ]
    });
}); 

 <div id="square"></div>
```

but the one below doesn't. Any ideas why? thanks

```
$(function Myfunction (id){
            $("#" + id).udraggable({
                containment: [ 0, 0, 8000, 8000],
                grid: [ 30, 30 ]
            });
        });

<img onclick="Myfunction(this.id)" src="files/pic/googleWebsite.png" id="googleWebsite" height="33">
```

Comment: Is there any error in console ?

Comment: doesn't look like it. I'm using Sublime text3 and sublimLiner... but I'm very new at this so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: The console is in the web browser, not your code editor. How to get to it depends on which browser you're testing in.

Comment: I'm using chrome will check it out

Answer (score 0):

It is not working due to wrong syntax of defining function. Just define function like this:

```
    function Myfunction(id){
        $("#" + id).udraggable({
            grid: [ 15, 15 ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: still no luck unfortunately

Comment: doesn't look like it. I'm using Sublime text3 and sublimLiner... but I'm very new at this so maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, changed `onclick` to `onload`

```
function Myfunction (id){
            $("#" + id).udraggable({
                containment: [ 0, 0, 8000, 8000],
                grid: [ 30, 30 ]
            });
        }

<img onload="Myfunction(this.id)" src="files/pic/googleWebsite.png" id="googleWebsite" height="33">
```

Comment: this works but why doesn't onclick? thanks very much btw

Comment: OK, you shouldn't bind the udraggable on click, ideally it should be done on DOM ready, In case if you have onclick, on first click of image the plugin will get initialize and now if you try to drag it will work.

Comment: you lost me there... sorry I'm very new to coding so what should I do if want onclick? can you give me a practical example?

Comment: you can use jquery .click api

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
    $ ("img").udraggable({
     grid:        [ 30, 30 ]
  });
  });
}); ---- that works but it make all images in the html draggable how can I make one the one I selected?

Comment: Give it a unique class <img class="draggable"/> and use $(".draggable") as selector

Comment: the prob with this solution is that I have several other dragable pictures but if I do a class they will all be selected and then they will be all over the place in the html i.e losing their position